# Rendering ssrs reports on an external website, if ssrs server is internal

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an internal / internal to our organization ssrs set up, means SSRS reports server url is only accessible inside our org. network . There are few ssrs reports which have parameters and drill down options, which need to be make available for our externals users on our  public portal. Public portal authentication is a custom form based authentication and Ssrs use active directory windows authentication.

I came across few articles using SSRS web services , so that I can use impersonation with  AD accounts. But only issue is reports are rendered in pdf, Excel format, the default ssrs pagination, parameters selection is lost.

How can I bring SSRS reports with their default UX to a public user, without exposing ssrs to outside world? I am using asp.net mvc5. I heard about report viewer controls for  asp.net webforms , but can that be achieved without making SSRS public. Please help.

Comment: Place the external SSRS in DMZ accessing the backend via reverse gateway. For internal users you can have a full SSRS instance separately. That's one idea.

Comment: @access_granted Thanks for reply. But in my scenario, there are few things going in parallel. The end public user, don't have/need access to SSRS dashboard (even if that in DMZ). Because , end user is using a custom form based authentication or Google authentication and once logged in, we need to impersonate him to a certain AD account as per his authorization or access level to render SSRS reports. My question is, is there a way to render toolbar/parameters optionlist without providing access to regaular SSRS Dashboard

Comment: I solved by hosting a Webform in my MVC WebApp and extended ReportViewer inside that webform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by hosting a Webform in my MVC WebApp and extended ReportViewer inside that webform. This webform is then consumed in my MVC view